# Restore read-only file from Deja-Dup

Tags: nautilus, permissions, deja-dup

I have a backup of my web server files (user=www-data) created by my main Ubuntu user (not root) that has read access to the web server file system.

I am unable to restore files via the Nautilus 'restore missing files' shortcut because my main user doesn't have wrote permission for the target folder.

Is there a way around this?  e.g. running the restore as root in some way?  Note that the backup archive is associated with my main user and not root so simply opening nautilus as root is no use since the backup isn't associated with 'root'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

1) Use the duplicity command line as root to directly restore your files.

or

2) Open the Deja Dup settings window and choose restore. When it asks you if you want to restore the files in-place or into a folder, choose into a folder. It will restore everything into that folder and then you can move anything you need into your system folders yourself.